# Issue adding new column within def local dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I find a strange behaviour regarding to localised dataframe variable impacting external dataframe (from the def function) when adding new columns in the local dataframe. Wonder if this can be prevented by some sort of settings.

Here is case 1, column C in the external dataframe is expectedly added by local dataframe within the def test:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'B' : [1,2,3,4]})

def test(data):
    # These 2 lines below are the only difference 
    # between case 1 & 2
    #data=data + 1 
    #data=data - 1

    data['C'] =  data['A'] + data['B']
    return data['C']

print("Before running test()")
print(data)
print("Returns from test()")
print(test(data))
print("data after running test()")
print(data)

Before running test()
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
Returns from test()
0    2
1    4
2    6
3    8
Name: C, dtype: int64
data after running test()
   A  B  C
0  1  1  2
1  2  2  4
2  3  3  6
3  4  4  8
```

In case 1, I thought the data within the def test(data): would have been localised so even if I add a new column, it would not affect the source dataframe outside the function. But the new column C is still added to the dataframe outside the test().

However, if I do modified the local data and then adding new column, the external dataframe is not impacted as in the following case 2:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'B' : [1,2,3,4]})

def test(data):
    # These 2 lines below are the only difference 
    # between case 1 & 2
    data=data + 1 
    data=data - 1

    data['C'] =  data['A'] + data['B']
    return data['C']

print("Before running test()")
print(data)
print("Returns from test()")
print(test(data))
print("data after running test()")
print(data)

Before running test()
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
Returns from test()
0    2
1    4
2    6
3    8
Name: C, dtype: int64
data after running test()
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
```

I can setup temp dataframe to avoid the problem but it is rather cumbersome. I would very much like to enforce the dataframe to be localised so that when I make changes or adding new column, the source / external dataframe would not be impacted.

Answer (score 0):

The `data = data + 1` assignment creates a new object, which you can see if you look at `id(data)` after the call. Without that, it's just modifying the same object in place (as in `test1` below):

```
In [11]: def test1(data):
    ...:     print(id(data))
    ...:     data['C'] = data['A'] + data['B']
    ...:     return data['C']

In [12]: data, id(data)
Out[12]:
(   A  B
 0  1  1
 1  2  2
 2  3  3
 3  4  4, 1413911641896)

In [13]: test1(data)
1413911641896
Out[13]:
0    2
1    4
2    6
3    8
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [14]: def test2(data):
    ...:     data = data + 1
    ...:     print(id(data))
    ...:     data['D'] = data['A'] + data['B']
    ...:     return data['D']

In [15]: test2(data)
1413912402128
Out[15]:
0     4
1     6
2     8
3    10
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the second case when you add the line

```
data=data + 1
```

you're creating a new instance of a dataframe modifying that instead of the original.
In the second case it's well known you can't modify a dataframe in a function without making a copy of it first, or else you modify the initial df as well

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that pandas does not make duplicate dataframe when assigning the df to another variable. Instead it is just assigning the "view" of the original df to the new variable. I suppose this make sense that Pandas make this as default to save memory consumption unless we specifically request a separate copy of the original df.

When I first ask the question, I already had this thesis. However, I did not know how to "force" a copy instead of a view. After some further trial with new "search keywords", I finally ran into the right documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

Anyway, to cut to the chase, here is my conclusion:

1. Pandas does not automatically create a localised version of df when the df is passed to a function as input (like def test1(df):)
2. If we want a localised df within the function, we must specifically make a "Deep" copy via the .copy(deep=True)function.

A new set of codes that work is as follows:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[4,5,6,7]})    
def test1(dfSource):
  df1 = dfSource.copy()
  df1['C'] = dfSource['A']+dfSource['B']
  return(df1)

print("\ndf0 before test1()\n"," id(df0):",id(df0),"\n",df0)
print("\nreturn from test1(df0):\n",test1(df0))
print("\ndf0 after test1()\n"," id(df0):",id(df0),"\n",df0)

Output:

df0 before test1()
  id(df0): 140102308422224 
    A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7

return from test1(df0):
    A  B   C
0  1  4   5
1  2  5   7
2  3  6   9
3  4  7  11

df0 after test1()
  id(df0): 140102308422224 
    A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7
```